# Return next element in stream

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator, java-stream

Need to get next element in stream. What about iterator?

```
student.getStudentGroupList().forEach(g -> { 
   g.getCourseList().forEach(c -> {         
      c.getThemeList().forEach(t -> {
         if (t.equalsIgnoreId(lastTheme)) {
           //return next 
         }
      });
   }); 
});
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear.
Do you want to return only one "next" element and exit the loop ? 
If only one element must be returned, then what if a next element also satifies a condition ? should it be returned, or shold it also be skipped ?
Or you want only to skip all elements that satisfy the condition, and collect all remaining elements that don't meet the condiion ?

Comment: @kordirko Yes i want to return just one element. Return next element if prev satisfies condition and makes some operations with it. I update my post, i think thats clear.

Comment: @ArtemDumanov, it's still completely unclear. Please post the desired input and desired output for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have multiple nested `forEach` calls, the way to "flatten" this all into a single stream is to use `flatMap`:

```
student.getStudentGroupList().stream()
       .flatMap(g -> g.getCourseList().stream())
       .flatMap(c -> c.getThemeList().stream())
       ...
```

This gets you a stream of all themes from all courses from all student groups.

If you want to get the very next element following a matching one, use this technique (Java 9 only): drop the leading, non-matching elements, skip the next element (which is the first match), and then get the following element.

```
       ...
       .dropWhile(t -> !yourCondition(t))
       .skip(1)
       .findFirst();
```

This returns `Optional<Theme>` containing the desired element, or an empty optional if none of the themes meet your condition, or if one does but there's no following element.

In your example you compare a theme to `lastTheme` which suggests to me the condition is about the previous element in the stream. If that's the case, it's different from what I outlined above, and if so, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (iter.hashNext()) {
    currentElement = iter.hasNext()
    if(//if iter.hashNext() and if currentElement satisfies the predicate) { 

       return iter.next();

   }
}
```